# Object {...} is neither a bytes object nor has an encode method while saving to text in Python Dask

Tags: python, dask

I have a big `json` file which I read with Dask in Python. Then I do some tweaking and filtering and try to save it to `json` again.

```
def flatten(record):
    return {
        'id': record['id'],
        'title': record['title'],
        'year': record['year'],
         ...
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dd = db.read_text('data.json',).map(json.loads)
    dd.filter(lambda x: 'title' in x.keys()) \
        .map(flatten) \
        .to_textfiles('*.json', encoding='utf-8')
```

First, I filter out all the objects that don't have the field `title`. Then, with `map`, I remove all the fields I don't want and create some new fields. And finally, I call the `to_textfiles` to save it to `json` again.

However, I get the error

```
TypeError: Object {...here goes the first object as I have created it...} is neither a bytes object nor has an encode method
```

The object is valid and tested in an online validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[to_textfiles](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.to_textfiles) expects a bag in which the elements are text. Just as you map with `json.loads` before manipulation, you will need to map with `json.dumps` before writing:

```
.map(json.dumps).to_textfiles('*.json', encoding='utf-8')
```